# How can I use GetNextWindow() in C#?

Tags: c#, windows, winapi

The Microsoft WinAPI documentation appears to suggest that user32.dll contains a function called [`GetNextWindow()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms633509(VS.85).aspx) which supposedly allows one to enumerate open windows in their Z order by calling this function repeatedly.

[Pinvoke](http://www.pinvoke.net/) usually gives me the necessary `DllImport` statement to use WinAPI functions from C#. However, for `GetNextWindow()` it doesn't have an entry. So I tried to construct my own:

```
[DllImport("user32.dll")]
static extern IntPtr GetNextWindow(IntPtr hWnd, uint wCmd);
```

Unfortunately, when trying to call this, I get an `EntryPointNotFoundException` saying:

```
Unable to find an entry point named 'GetNextWindow' in DLL 'user32.dll'.
```

This seems to apply only to `GetNextWindow()`; other functions that are listed on Pinvoke are fine. I can call `GetTopWindow()` and `GetWindowText()` without throwing an exception.

Of course, if you can suggest a completely different way to enumerate windows in their current Z order, I'm happy to hear that too.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

**GetNextWindow()** is actually a macro for **GetWindow()**, rather than an actual API method. It's for backward compatibility with the Win16 API.

```
[DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
static extern IntPtr GetWindow(IntPtr hWnd, uint uCmd);

enum GetWindow_Cmd : uint {
    GW_HWNDFIRST = 0,
    GW_HWNDLAST = 1,
    GW_HWNDNEXT = 2,
    GW_HWNDPREV = 3,
    GW_OWNER = 4,
    GW_CHILD = 5,
    GW_ENABLEDPOPUP = 6
}
```

(From [Pinvoke.net](http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/user32/GetWindow.html))

Comment: Right. And this thread (http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/vbgeneral/thread/afa69b03-5425-4124-b9b4-f8c6cb9bcc9c) shows how to use it to get "next"

Comment: What's the point of GetNextWindow() besides confusing poor pinvokers if it takes the same arguments as GetWindow() then?

Comment: It's included for backwards compatibility with old code. As for why they chose to implement it using a macro, I would guess that it's to eliminate an intermediate function call (back when compilers weren't as good at optimization), but I don't know for sure. That's probably a good question for [Raymond Chen](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/).

Answer (score 2):

GetNextWindow is a c++ macro that calls GetWindow, so you cannot call it from .NET. Call GetWindow instead.

From [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms633509%28VS.85%29.aspx):

> Using this function is the same as calling the GetWindow function with the GW_HWNDNEXT or GW_HWNDPREV flag set

Comment: Currently having trouble finding, how are you supposed to determine when you've reached the end?