# IUIAutomationElement FindAll method wrong elements count

Tags: windows, ui-automation

I am using IUIAutomationElement FindAll method to return all the elements but i am having a problem.
I am interacting the explorer.exe and i am getting all the elements in the CabinetWClass.
FindAll method works like a charm but when it comes to count the elements that are not visible in the control it fails. So basically if there are elements that we need to scroll down the control to be able to see them, FindAll method will not count them so it will return a wrong number of the elements which means it's lenght is going to be wrong.
It will basically count and return only the elements that are visible on our screen.

Anyone knows if there is a debug for this?
I am searching msdn but i am not finding any work around for this.

This is the link for the FindAll method: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ee696027(v=vs.85).aspx

Answer (score 0):

Functions `EnumWindows` and `EnumChildWindows` can walk all existing (visible and invisible) native windows (they are all native for explorer.exe). This is [an example for C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19867402/how-can-i-use-enumwindows-to-find-windows-with-a-specific-caption-title). But if you need to see invisible content elements (like ListItem), such method is useless.