# C# WinAPI Check for Window Text from Static

Tags: c#, .net, winapi, ipc

I am attempting to determine whether a Window with the Class Name of "Static", **CONTAINS** "Scan finished." via .NET/C#.

Specifically, I have automated the use of RogueKiller and would like to detect when the "Scan" is done.

I have tried numerous PInvoke methods, but nothing I can find allows me to do (pseudo) Caption.Contains("Scan finished");.

Any help would be wonderful!

The Window Structure Works as:

Parent (RogueKiller™...etc)
Windows - Class:Static, Caption: 
    Scan finished.      Please look at the different tabs and delete items with the buttons

I need to detect "Scan finished".

Comment: Which PInvoke methods did you try? GetClassName, GetChild and GetDesktop combos didn't work?

Comment: I tried EnumWindows, etc. I am attempting to find a Child Window, and I can find it specifically with exact caption, but the caption can vary, so I need to check if it "Contains" the text.

Comment: All windows are children of the desktop (GetDesktop and GetWindow (when I said GetChild)). You can determine the class name using GetClassName. GetWindowText gets the text.

Comment: I required a Child Window of a Process, and to detect it's Caption. See updated question.

Comment: This is exactly the sort of thing that UI Automation was designed for. You want to trigger when a child element's `Name` changes, then compare the `Name` to your desired string.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19867402

Comment: Use WM_GETTEXTLENGTH -> WM_GETTEXT rather than GetWindowText() as you are cross-process and not looking for a title caption. To find a child window pass the parents HWND to EnumChildWindows().  If you are new to this as suggested you may like to look at UI Automation which abstracts the Win32 stuff.

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to call [EnumWindows](http://pinvoke.net/default.aspx/user32/EnumWindows.html) and call [GetWindowText](http://pinvoke.net/default.aspx/user32/GetWindowText.html) in your callback.  I hesitate to copy/paste another StackOverflow answer.  So for a detailed example, see [How can I use EnumWindows to find windows with a specific caption/title?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19867402/)

Comment: Could you give me a working example (pseudo okay)? I'm not sure how to go about that....