# Finding multiple windows with the same title

Tags: c#, winapi

I am starting an executable several times like this

```
Process proc = new Process();
proc.StartInfo.FileName = path + "/BuiltGame.exe";
proc.Start();

Process proc1 = new Process();
proc1.StartInfo.FileName = path + "/BuiltGame.exe";
proc1.Start();
```

Now I want to resize and move the spawned windows.

I am currently using MoveWindow and FindWindow

```
[DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
internal static extern bool MoveWindow(IntPtr hWnd, int X, int Y, int nWidth, int nHeight, bool bRepaint);
[DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
internal static extern IntPtr FindWindow(string windowClass, string title);
```

Initially I thought that I could just use the handle from the spawned process

```
 MoveWindow(proc.Handle, 0, 0, 100, 100, true);
```

But it didn't work and I tried to use `FindWindow`

```
IntPtr Handle = FindWindow(null,"MyWindowTitle")
```

Which indeed worked and the returned handle from `FindWindow` is a different one that from `Process.Handle`

After that I tried to use

```
 MoveWindow(proc.MainWindowHandle, 0, 0, 100, 100, true);
```

But `MainWindowHandle` is just 0.

The problem that I now have is that I want to start multiple processes and get the correct window handle from each window but `FindWindow` only returns the first one.

How would I do this?

Comment: Have you tried `EnumWindows`? The accepted answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19867402/how-can-i-use-enumwindows-to-find-windows-with-a-specific-caption-title) show how to call it from C#.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Call [`EnumWindows`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633497.aspx) to enumerate top-level windows. For each such window, call [`GetWindowText`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633520.aspx) to find out its text which you can then compare against your target value.

If you are looking for windows in a specific process, use `GetWindowThreadProcessId`.

Comment: Actually the OP probably wants to use `GetWindowThreadProcessId` to compare against the target process, since the window titles will all be the same.

Comment: @Jonathan That depends. Yes if you want to find a window from a specific process. But perhaps you want to find all such windows.

Comment: *"The problem that I now have is that I want to start multiple processes and get the correct window handle from each window but FindWindow only returns the first one"* suggests he wants to match windows to processes.

Answer (score 0):

I used this when launching multiple windows for a game, but I'm also waiting a few seconds for it to start up and show a window. If you're getting the MainWindowHandle before the window has a chance to initialize, then this may be some of the issue.  This lets me set each position as I'm cycling through processes to launch, before I continue to the next

```
            // Launch each process
            using (Process myProcess = new Process())
            {
                myProcess.StartInfo.FileName = Folder + "\\executable.exe";
                myProcess.StartInfo.WorkingDirectory = Folder;
                myProcess.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
                myProcess.StartInfo.RedirectStandardInput = true;
                
                myProcess.Start();

                // Wait for process to start up, default 2000ms set elsewhere
                await Task.Delay(LaunchDelayTime);

                // If found, position it.
                if (myProcess.MainWindowHandle != IntPtr.Zero)
                {
                    // Move to WindowLeft x WindowTop, set elsewhere
                    SetWindowPos(myProcess.MainWindowHandle, IntPtr.Zero, (int)WindowLeft, (int)WindowTop, 0, 0, SWP_NOSIZE | SWP_NOZORDER);
                }
            }
```