# How can i find external process task window exe file location?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

```
Process[] processlist = Process.GetProcesses();
List<string> names = new List<string>();

foreach (Process process in processlist)
{
    if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(process.MainWindowTitle))
    {
        if (process.MainWindowTitle.Contains("GrAD"))
        {                       
            CaptureApplication(process.MainWindowTitle);
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

In the process.MainWindowTitle in the MainWindowTitles i see: GrADS 2.0.2.oga.2
This is fired from the external process Xming. Xming is a small server that connect to the internet and then show a console window and the GrADS 2.0.2.oga.2 is the title of the window but i can't find in any place this GrADS 2.0.2.oga.2 file exe file. I can see the Xming on tray icon but i tried in Task Manager can't find the GrADS 2.0.2.oga.2 exe file on my hard disk.

[Task Manager](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dcJ3D.jpg)

```
CaptureApplication(process.MainWindowTitle);
```

When CaptureApplication get the MainWindowTitle in this case GrADS 2.0.2.oga.2 it should capture the window and stick it add it to the pictureBox on form1.
But it's not.

```
public void CaptureApplication(string _title)
{
    string _wndcls = "ConsoleWindowClass";
    STARTUPINFO si = new STARTUPINFO();
    PROCESS_INFORMATION pi = new PROCESS_INFORMATION();
    CreateProcess(_title, null, IntPtr.Zero, IntPtr.Zero, false, 0, IntPtr.Zero, null, ref si, out pi);
    IntPtr _wndConsole = IntPtr.Zero;

    for (int i = 0; i < 30; i++)
    {
        _wndConsole = FindWindow(_wndcls, _title);
        if (_wndConsole == IntPtr.Zero)
        {
            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(10);
            continue;
        }
        break; 
    }    

    IntPtr value = SetParent(_wndConsole, this.pictureBox1.Handle);
    int style = GetWindowLong(_wndConsole, -16);
    style &= -12582913;
    SetWindowLong(_wndConsole, -16, style);
    SendMessage(_wndConsole, WM_SYSCOMMAND, SC_MAXIMIZE, 0);
}
```

Maybe GrADS 2.0.2.oga.2 is not exe file not a process ? I can't figure out how to capture it.

[GrADS 2.0.2.oga.2 screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tmuli.jpg)

This window on the left i need to capture.
Maybe the GrADS 2.0.2.oga.2 is not a self process ? It is showing on after the Xming is running.

Comment: Wouldn't Xming be the process name, and in that case, also the MainWindowTitle? Then GrADS 2.0.2.oga.2 woudn't be an exe, just the child window title.

Comment: Tim might be but i want to capture the child window title the GrADS 2.0.2.oga.2 and not the Xming.exe if i try to cpature the Xming process.Name or MainWindowTitle it's not showing the GrADS 2.0.2.oga.2 in the pictureBox. I want to capture the GrADS 2.0.2.oga.2

Comment: If it's a child window and you're trying to get the window handle, you may have to use this approach: http://stackoverflow.com/a/20276701/1432845

Comment: You might want to read [Is it legal to have a cross-process parent/child or owner/owned window relationship?](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20130412-00/?p=4683/) by Raymond Chen before going much further. "Yes, it is technically legal.

It is also technically legal to juggle chainsaws. ... they become near-impossible to manage if one or both of the windows involved is unaware that it is participating in a cross-process window tree"