# Processing a running presentation's output in Unity(C#)

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, stream, powerpoint, presentation

I ran into a problem while trying to stream the "Output" of a running PowerPoint Presentation to a Unity3d Application.

**Context:** Ive gotta develop a VR presenting service for Unity (C#), where a user (wearing an Oculus Rift) holds a presentation in a virtual environment. 
The presentation itself gotta be displayed on a plane right behind the user. 
At the moment, every slide of the presentation is saved as single .png file and later loaded into the scene.

**Problem:**
Since the old implementation doesn't support any kind of slide interactivity, I have to revise the whole presentation system.
Going for- and backwards within the presentation has been realized by redirecting incoming keystrokes to the PowerPoint Presentaion Window, as shown here:
[How can I use EnumWindows to find windows with a specific caption/title?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19867402/how-can-i-use-enumwindows-to-find-windows-with-a-specific-caption-title)
In terms of displaying the slides, I tried using the *Online PowerPoint Show* which unfortunately caused too much delay to be properly used in Unity. And to be quite honest, due to a lack of knowledge, that's pretty much everything I've been able to try so far.

**My actual Question:**
Is there a way to get the rendered image/video of the PowerPoint Presentation while it's running?

**A.** From the PowerPoint Application itself or  **B.** From the video-card and make it available for the Unity Application?
Or is there **C.** any other idea about how to solve this problem?

Thanks in advance + forgive me my english skills.

Comment: I would go for option B and just screengrab into unity, otherwise this is a pretty complicated task

Comment: Yea, well. Can you also tell me how? And is that even possible, while Powerpoint is running in the background? I have no clue, whether the video card even renders the presentation or not while in BG.

Comment: you'd have to use another computer with screen dupliaction and grab via something like Blackmagic Intenstiy. it is possible to grab window contents - but I don't know any details